# Regex that matches an IP address after an word

Tags: regex, ip

This is an HTML (actually there is a JS part of it) text stored as a string in my C# application:

```
...
var wanPara = new Array(
    0, "00-1D-0F-EA-9C-91", "86.126.104.62", 3, "255.255.255.255", 0, 0, "86.126.104.62", 0, 1, 0, "213.154.124.1 , 193.231.252.1", "0 day(s) 07:40:24", "Connected", "", 0, 
    0,0 );
...
```

And i want to create a regex that will give me the text *86.126.104.62*.
The IP may vary, so thats why i want to get it. For this example is 86.126.104.62.
Can you please give me some suggestions ?

Comment: Please reword your question. It is hard to see what you are actually doing.  What have you tried? Where are you stuck?  Refer to [this post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) about how to write a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple version:**

```
\bwanPara\b(.|\r|\n)*?\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b
```

**Complex version:**

```
\bwanPara\b(.|\r|\n)*?\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))\b
```

Then extract the second group.

**A few useful notes:**

`\b` - word boundary
`(.|\r|\n)` - a wild-card or a carriage return or a line break
`(.|\r|\n)*?` - zero or more wild-card or carriage return or line break, non greedily
`\d` - digit
`\d{1,3}` - one to three digits
`\.` - escaped `.`
`[X-Y]` - any single character from X to Y

IP regex taken from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).

Comment: `.` encompasses `\r` as well.

Comment: Minor detail; this matches 0.0.0.0 --- can the first digit really be a zero?